# Propagating events in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, kivy, kde-plasma

I have modified this example at the end of this [tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html) a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='button 1'))
        cb = CustomBtn()
        cb.bind(pressed=self.btn_pressed)
        self.add_widget(cb)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='button 2'))

    def btn_pressed(self, instance, pos):
        print(f'4444 RootWidget.btn_pressed, instance: {instance} pos: {pos}')


class CustomBtn(Widget):
    pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(f'1111 CustomButton.on_touch_down, touch id: {id(touch)}, touch {touch}')
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f'2222 CustomButton.on_touch_down, collision, self.pressed: {self.pressed}')
            self.pressed = touch.pos
            # we consumed the touch. return False here to propagate
            # the touch further to the children.
            return True
        return super(CustomBtn, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_pressed(self, instance, pos):
        print(f'3333 CustomButton.on_pressed, instance: {instance} pos: {pos}')


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Now, when I press `button 1`, I get this:

```
1111 CustomButton.on_touch_down, touch id: 140523635041336, touch <MouseMotionEvent spos=(0.1875, 0.31999999999999995) pos=(150.0, 191.99999999999997)>
```

Why? This should be handled in `Button(text='button 1')`, no?

Sure, since `collide_point` call detects that this touch down has happened outside custom button's area, this does not backfire, but why is this happening in the first place?

Next, to make this even weirder, when I click `button 2`, this is not happening (i.e. nothing gets printed).

Why (and how?) are events dispatched here?

Kivy: 1.11.1.
OS: Debian 10 (buster) amd64
GUI: KDE Plasma.
Python: 3.7.

Startup log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/user/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-05-08_16.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/user/projects/kvapp/venv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (default, Feb 22 2019, 18:56:07) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/user/projects/kvapp/venv37/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.43'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events are propagated to all the `Widgets` in the `Window` until any one of them stops the propagation. The `on_touch_down()` methods are called for each `Button` in the reverse order that they were added, that is:

1. Button 2
2. CustomBtn
3. Button 1

If the touch position is on Button 2, its `on_touch_down()` returns `True` and stops the event propagation, so no other `Widget` gets that event. That is why pressing Button 2 produces no printing.

When you click on Button 1, Button 2 sees it first, but since it is not within Button 2, the event is ignored and allowed to propagate on to `CustomBtn`. The `CustomBtn` `on_touch_down()` prints the `1111` message, but since the touch is outside the `CustomBtn`, it also allows the propagation to continue. Now Button 1 gets the event and processes it, stopping the propagation.

When you click on the `CustomBtn`, the Button 2 again sees it first, but allow the propagation to continue. Then `CustomBtn` sees the event, prints the `1111` message, determines that the touch is on the `CustomBtn`,  so the `2222` message is printed, the `pressed` property is modified (causing the `on_pressed()` method to be triggered), and the bound `btn_pressed()` method is also triggered. The propagation is then stopped (by the `True` return), so Button 1 never sees this event.